# Function value always getting multiplied by 2

Tags: java, function

I have created a function "m7" in my class but this function is always returning value getting multiplied by 2.
If I am running this function in "psvm" it is printing the right value.
In my Alice class, the method m7() is returning 10 which is incorrect but if I am running this method in psvm then it is returning 5 which is correct.

```
    package com.math.functions;

import java.util.*;

public class Alice {
    Integer[] rank= new Integer[7];
    Integer n=65;
    int count=0;
    public Alice() {
        rank[0]=100;
        rank[1]=100;
        rank[2]=90;
        rank[3]=80;
        rank[4]=75;
        rank[5]=60;
        rank[6]=n;
        //rank[6]=20;
        //rank[7]=10;
        //rank[8]=n;
        Arrays.sort(rank, Collections.reverseOrder());
    }
    public void print() {

        for (Integer a : rank) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
    public int m7() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
            if (rank[i] == n) {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public void res(){
        int s = m7();
        System.out.println("this is the value of s here :"+s);
        Set<Integer> hash_Set = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<=s/2;i++){
            System.out.println("hii");
            hash_Set.add(rank[i]);
        }
        for(Integer o:hash_Set){
            System.out.println(o);
            System.out.println("rank:"+hash_Set.size());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alice a=new Alice();
        a.print();
        System.out.println("this is: "+a.m7());
        a.res();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also: do yourself (and others you want to read your code) a favour and give you methods (and variables etc) sensible names. `m7` is essentially meaningless to somebody without context.

Comment: You're pretty lucky that your example values are all <= 100. If they were larger than 128, then your usage of `Integer` would cause you some trouble. Use `int` instead, or use `.equals()` for comparison, not `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the value of `count` from the previous time you run it.

Don't declare `count` as a member variable, make it a local variable.

```
public int m7() {
    int count = 0; // HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
        if (rank[i] == n) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```